# calling modal from another component in react native wont open modal

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am trying to open a modal from another component.
this is in my parent component:

```
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.gateBtn}
  onPress={() => {
    setModalVisible(true);
  }}
>
  <Text style={styles.gateBtnText}>Show Modal</Text>
  <OpenModal isModalVisible={modalVisible} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and this is my OpenModal.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Alert,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from "react-native";

function OpenModal(props) {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <View style={styles.modalView}>
          <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
            onPress={() => {
              setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  openButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
export default OpenModal;
```

however It seems like I am doing something wrong,
I am trying to pass `modalVisible` to OpenModal by using `isModalVisible={modalVisible}` and `modalVisible` is already defined as false, when clicking on the button it becomes true, but in my OpenModal component It seems like its undefined, and it doesnt open the modal at all. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass in the setModalVision, then use the props.modalVisible from the parent component.

in parent

```
<OpenModal isModalVisible={modalVisible} setModalVisible={setModalVisible} />
```

child component

```
function OpenModal(props) {
  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={props.isModalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <View style={styles.modalView}>
          <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
            onPress={() => {
              props.setModalVisible(!props.isModalVisible);
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: i had a typo i just fixed.

Comment: this one the modal is already open and I cant close it!

Comment: props.modalVisible is undefined inside OpenModal component.

Comment: thank you, it should be instead of props.modalVisible to  props.isModalVisible, and this one works thank u

Comment: oh right, you changed the name when passing it into the OpenModal. forgot about that. Updated